# Facebook bot greeting text in arabic is showing question marks?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am using this `node.js` script to update my Facebook bot greeting text, but when I apply it I see question marks instead of characters?

```
  var request = require('request');

//=========================================================
// Facebook setup // Run only when need updating.
//=========================================================

// Set FB bot greeting text
facebookThreadAPI('./fb-greeting-text.json', 'Greeting Text');
// Set FB bot get started button
facebookThreadAPI('./fb-get-started-button.json', 'Get Started Button');

// Calls the Facebook graph api to change various bot settings
function facebookThreadAPI(jsonFile, cmd){
    // Start the request
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=djsaldksa',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        form: require(jsonFile)
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Print out the response body
            console.log(cmd+": Updated.");
            console.log(body);
        } else { 
            // TODO: Handle errors
            console.log(cmd+": Failed. Need to handle errors.");
            console.log(body);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is the greeting file

```
{
  "setting_type":"greeting",
  "greeting":{  
    "text":"مرحبا "
  }
}
```

Is there a limitation that its in English only?

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately Bot framework is not limited to English only.
All you need is just to set `Locale` parameter for Arabic language before sending desired message. Examples of it can be found [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/localization/#navtitle).

Comment: But I am just updating it once , not a whole settings. Do i need to use some json encoding?